# Generate multiple csv file depending of IDRow

Tags: linux, database, bash, sqlite, csv

I have a small script that takes the values from a table and puts then in a csv file. The problem is that I'm not able to generante multiple csv files depending of the IDRow.

```
if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    echo "Database path"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$2" = "" ]
then
    echo "Csv file output path"
exit 1
fi

db=$1
t=($(sqlite3 $db ".tables 'myTable'"))

for i in "${t[@]}"
do
    sqlite3 $db<<- EXIT_HERE
    .mode csv
    .separator ;
    .output $2/$i.csv
    SELECT IDRow,strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',Date),Value FROM $i order by IDRow;
    .exit
    EXIT_HERE
    echo "$i.csv generated"
done
```

What I get in the csv file is this:

> IDRow; Datetime;Value
>   3;06-03-2017 10:53:40;120
>   3;06-03-2017 10:53:41;120
>   4;06-03-2017 11:41:22;12000
>   4;06-03-2017 11:41:23;12000
>   5;06-03-2017 11:51:49;15000
>   5;06-03-2017 11:51:50;15000

How can I get 3 different files?Thanks

Comment: You already have a loop for the table names. Add another loop.

Comment: add `WHERE id_row = '$i' before the `order by`. Good luck.

Comment: I found a solution by adding another query and a for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I found

```
if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    echo "Database path"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$2" = "" ]
then
    echo "Csv file output path"
exit 1
fi

db=$1
t=($(sqlite3 $db ".tables"))
row=(sqlite3 $1 "select IDRow from mytable group by IDRow")

for i in "${row[@]}"; do
    for j in "${table[@]}"; do
        sqlite3 $db<<- EXIT_HERE
        .mode csv
        .separator ;
        .output $2/$i.csv
         SELECT IDRow,Date,Value FROM $j order by IDRow=$i;
        .exit
        EXIT_HERE
    done
 done
```

Thank you